# SQL table stopping me from adding foreign key

Tags: sql

I'm creating a SQL table in VS that stores what rooms each client is, So the table has `RoomId (int)` and `UserID (int)`.

Because I only want to add to the table only rooms and clients that exist they are both keys that have a foreign key to 2 tables, one that stores `RoomID` and Name and another that stores `Client ID` and Name.

`Room` and `UserId` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersInRoomsTable]
(
    RoomId INT NOT NULL,
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_RS PRIMARY KEY(RoomId, UserId), 
    CONSTRAINT [fk_room] FOREIGN KEY([RoomId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[RoomsTable]([RoomId]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_user] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfoTable] ([UserId])
);
```

Table that stores all the users:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfoTable] 
(
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]   INT           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_roomuser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserName] ASC, [UserId] ASC)
);
```

Table that stores all the rooms

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoomsTable] 
(
    [RoomId]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [RoomName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoomId] ASC)
);
```

Everything works except the last line in the `Rooms` and users table:

```
    CONSTRAINT [fk_user] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfoTable] ([UserId])
```

When I try to Update the table I get an error SQL71516:

> SQL71516: The referenced table '[dbo].[UserInfoTable]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key.
> If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted

How can I solve this problem and what is causing it?

**Edit**: I think I know what is code is colliding: For some reason I can not have a foreign key connecting to a key that contains 2 indexes IE: fk_user is a Fk to table UserInfoTable that has 2 keys (UserID and UserName)
is there a way to pass this obstacle?

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the tag for the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of a foreign key have to match the columns they reference by number, type and order.

You have a primary key on `userinfotable` of `(username, userid)`. But in `usersinroomstable` you are trying to let the foreign key `(userid)` to reference that. The number of columns doesn't match, so the foreign key cannot be added.

Presumably the `username` shouldn't really be part of the primary key of `userinfotable` and got there by accident. Remove it from the primary key constraint.

Or, if `username` has to be in the primary key, add such a column to the table `usersinroomstable` and add it to the foreign key constraint.

Comment: I need the username to be a primary key. Can you help me how to change the the line to include the username?




This doesn't work: 
 CONSTRAINT [fk_user] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId],[UserName]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfoTable] ([UserId],[UserName])

Comment: @Ratatat12: Like wrote, add a column for the username to `usersinroomstable` and include it in the foreign key.

Comment: Ya, I added a column for or the username to usersinroomstable but i dont know the code how to include more than one: I tried to change the lines and it didn't work: 
CONSTRAINT PK_RS PRIMARY KEY(RoomId, UserId, UserName), 
 CONSTRAINT [fk_user] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId],[UserName]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInfoTable] ([UserId],[UserName]),

Comment: @Ratatat12: Read my answer again... I clearly said the order must match. `username` comes first in the primary key. (But I still don't think `username` should be part of the primary key. You don't want `username` to be unique by any chance? If yes then, well, it isn't two tuples like `('Fred', 1)` and `('Fred', 2)` are perfectly legal in your schema...)